# Docker Storm Cluster Example

Tags: docker, apache-storm, docker-compose

Has any one looked at https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-docker

How exactly do you run an example topology on the cluster?

This might be a docker question but although the project is very useful the is no simple documentation of how to run a helloworld topology on it.

Comment: The project worked out of the box for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try out https://github.com/wurstmeister/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-test for some small examples

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried @Stumpy 's recommendation (in my case instead of localhost, 192.168.103) and the port is 49181 (even though I tried 4242, 49773, 49772, and 4900). I also went through the URL you provided.

I get 'unknownHostException'. If I leave out the port, I get 'connection refused'.

The second is obvious - no process is listening on the original ports (Docker processes). The first is surprising, it means (I think) that the code cannot interpret the IP together with the port as a valid address. 
Any help would be appreciated. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the host address with:

`storm -c nimbus.host=localhost:4242 jar class`

where 4242 is the port used for the container who run the nimbus.